# Elm - How to decode a json list of objects into a Dict

Tags: json, elm

Given a JSON list of objects e.g.:

```
[{"id":"1", "name":"Jane"},{"id":"2", "name":"Joe"}]
```

How do I decode this into a `Dict String Foo` with the `id` as keys and where `Foo` is a record of type `{id: String, name: String}`? (Note that the record also contains the id.)

Comment: why do you want the record both inside and outside the foo record?

Comment: I take it you mean the `id`? Unknown. This is a repost of a question on the Elm slack and I'm not the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use for example a combination of [`Json.Decode.list`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#list), [`Json.Decode.map2`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode#map2), [`Dict.fromList`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Dict#fromList) and [`Tuple.pair`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Tuple#pair) :

```
import Dict exposing (Dict)
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder)

type alias Foo =
    { id : String, name : String }

fooDecoder : Decoder Foo
fooDecoder =
    Decode.map2 Foo (Decode.field "id" Decode.string) (Decode.field "name" Decode.string)

theDecoder : Decoder (Dict String Foo)
theDecoder =
    Decode.list (Decode.map2 Tuple.pair (Decode.field "id" Decode.string) fooDecoder)
        |> Decode.map Dict.fromList
```